# What is the difference between createdAt and creationTime?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

After signing in a [user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User) by using Sign In With Google, the user object has a `metadata` property, which has `createdAt` and `creationTime`. What's difference? What are the different use cases/when should I use what? This can also apply to `lastLoginAt` and `lastSignInTime`. Thanks.

This is the user object and I have highlighted the part in question:
[The user object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odWWK.png)

Comment: That link you provided to the User object definition shows neither `createdAt` nor `creationTime`.  What exactly are you looking at?

Comment: That link shows the user object that is put into local storage after a user is logged in, I added that for clarity.

Comment: I have added an image to make it as clear as possible, sorry about that.

Comment: You're talking about the metadata object inside the user object.  If you click through, you will see documentation about that.  Note that not all of the fields you see are even mentioned in the API docs, which means they are probably not supported and can change without notice. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.UserMetadata